# Git merge cannot merge newer commits into develop branch?

Tags: git

I use git-flow manage a project.  `develop` branch as default branch, and `feature|hotfix|bugfix/xxxx` branch as feature branch.

current I got a problem:

`git checkout develop`
`git merge origin/hotfix/555`
The command message returns: `Already up to date.`
Then I checked the code, nothing changed. sad ...

But `hotfix/555` branch has many newer commits and changes compare with `develop` branch.

Got no idea why `git merge` does not merge these changes into `develop` branch?

below is a screenshot shows up one of the differences between these two branchs:

[image]

Comment: Is origin/hotfix/555 the same as hotfix/555?

Comment: Maybe your local hotfix branch has newer commit not the remote/hotfix.
Try git merge hotfix

Comment: @BobJacobsen   Yes, totally same.

Comment: @coder3101  Tried, still no effects.

Answer (score 0):

First, `origin/develop` might not be the same as `develop`: do a pull first on your develop branch, to ensure it is at the same state as `origin/develop`.
Same idea for hotfix (local branch) compared to origin/hotfix. Pull first.

Second, look at the graph of commits: you need to see commits in hotfix more recent than the last merge to develop.